Invers map of charst is locally smooth
I want to understand the proof of the following Theorem:
Let $\sigma: U \to R^n$  be a chart (i.e injetive, regular, paramatrized manifold in $R^n$ BUT the invers on the imgae is not required to be continuose) on a manifold $S \subset R^n$. Let $p_0\in\sigma(U)$. Then $\sigma^{-1}$ has a smooth extension in an open neighborhood of $p_0$. Moreover if $p_0 = \sigma(q_0)$ then there are open neighborhoods $W\subset R^n$ and $V\subset U$ of $p_0$ and $q_0$ such that $\sigma(V) = S\cap W$ and there is $\varphi: W \to V$ smooth such that $\varphi(\sigma(q)) = q$ and $\sigma(\varphi(p)) = p $ for all $q \in V$ and $p\in S\cap W$.
First of all to the statement, is the Moreoverpart not just a rephrasement of the part before? I have also a lot of questions to the proof. I will state here the proof as it is in my lecture notes and write whenever I dont understand a step. But maybe it would be even more important for me what is going on in this proof and how to think about it then to understand each step precisly. For me at the moment this proof is just a technical mess. Maybe someone can help me. My Lecture notes let the proof go the following way:
By another Lemma we no that there is a open neighborhood of $p_0$ $\tilde W \in R^n$ such that $S \cap \tilde W$ is paramatrized as graph of a function lets say $\tilde \sigma (x) = (x,h(x)). $ (???what is $\tilde \sigma$ here???) with a smooth map $h: \tilde U \to R^{n-m}$ for a open set $\tilde U \subset R^m$. Moreover $\tilde \sigma(\tilde U))= S \cap \tilde W$ and $\pi \tilde \sigma(x)) = x$ for $\pi:R^n \to R^m$ the projection on first m coordinates.
Now the proof states that it follows trivially that $\tilde \sigma(\pi (p)) = p$ for all $p \in S \cap \tilde W$ (???WHY???). Let $U_1 = \sigma^{-1}(\tilde W) \subset U$ open neighborhood of $q_0$.Then $\pi_1 \sigma: U_1 \to \tilde U$ is smooth. Moreover it follows that $\tilde \sigma (\pi \sigma) = \sigma$ (???WHY???) and hence $D(\tilde \sigma) D(\pi \sigma)= D \sigma$ which has independent columns. Hence $Det(D(\pi \sigma) (q_0) \not= 0$.
Now by the invers function theorem we find $V \subset U_1$ and $\tilde V \subset \tilde U$ open around $q_0$ and $\pi(\sigma(q_0))$ s.t $\pi \sigma: V \to \tilde V$ is a diffeomorphism. Hence $\sigma$ is a reparametrazation of $\tilde \sigma$ (??? What does this even mean???). Now $W = \tilde W \cap \pi^{-1}(\tilde V) \subset R^n$ open and does the job with $\varphi = (\pi \sigma)^{-1}\pi$ (??? I dont understand what is going on here???).
Sorry for the long proof, but I would appreciate help very much.
